# Individual loading animation for each page with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, loading

I want each of my pages to have different loading animations when loading. How can i achieve this?

It is not possible to put the loading component on the page component like this:

```
//Page component
Page.Loader = SomeLoaderComponent

//_app.tsx
const Loader = Component.Loader || DefaultLoader;
```

This will not work because "Component(the page)" isnt loaded/rendered yet.

I have also tried dynamic import with next.js, so that i can import the correct page based on the url, and then get the correct loader. My initial plan was to add the Loader to the page component, as shown at the first line in the code above. That does not work because I have to give an explicit path.

```
const getLoader = (pagePath: string): ComponentType => {
  const Loader = dynamic(() => import(pagePath));
  return Page.Loader;
};
```

This is stated in the Next.js docs: [image]

So the question is: How can I get a custom loader per page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Suspense and lazy to accomplish your task.

lets say you have ComponentA.js as follows

```
const ComponentA = () => {
   return <div>Helloooo</div>
}
```

You can create another component WrapperA.js file

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const WrapperA = React.lazy(() => import('./ComponentA'));

function WrapperA() {
   return (
     <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
         <ComponentA />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the place of `<div>Loading...</div>` you can have any loader component you like. and export WrapperA to your routes or tab as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont think this will work. I still need to dynamically change the loader depending on which page is loading on the server side.

Comment: you mean to say based on pagination number that is currently running in the backend?

Comment: I am using Next.js, so det frontend is kind of both frontend and backend (SSR). So when a page is loading server side I want different loading animations on different pages to be shown to the user. Lets say I am loading av page which contains a data grid, then I want the loader to be a skeleton of that grid. I want to dynamically change the loading, and therefore I need a way to connect the loading and the page before the page is loaded.